# how to archive or delete cassandra data after receiving event in wso2bam

Tags: cassandra, wso2-bam

I use WSO2BAM in version 2.3.0 where I defined a stream holding much amount of data in Cassandra datasource. Currently my Hive script processes all events from keyspace where 99% of data is unneccesary. And it takes disk space too.

My idea is to clear this data after it becomes unnecessary.

The format of stream is: 
    {"streamId":"kroki_i_kolejki_zlecen:1.0.0","name":"kroki_i_kolejki_zlecen","version":"1.0.0","nickName":"Kroki i kolejki zlecen","description":"Wyniki i daty zamkniecia zlecen","payloadData":[{"name":"casenum","type":"STRING"},{"name":"type_id","type":"STRING"},{"name":"id_zlecenie","type":"STRING"},{"name":"sid","type":"STRING"},{"name":"step_name","type":"STRING"},{"name":"proc_name","type":"STRING"},{"name":"step_desc","type":"STRING"},{"name":"audit_date","type":"STRING"},{"name":"audit_usecs","type":"STRING"},{"name":"user_name","type":"STRING"}]}

My intention is to delete data with the same column *payload_id_zlecenie* after I receive event with specific *payload_type_id*.
In relational database it would be equal to query:

```
delete from kroki_i_kolejki_zlecen where payload_id_zlecenie = [argument];
```

Is it possible to do?

Comment: While you certainly can delete by a primary key in Cassandra, you may want to reconsider your technology choice.  Cassandra is good at many things, but deletion is not one of them.  If you're intending to delete 99% of the data that you store, you are going to run into some performance problems.  You also won't get that disk space back for ~10 days by default due to the GCGrace period.

Comment: I tried to delete data from Cassandra, but there is a problem that wso2bam has inbuilt Cassandra. I don't know how to use cqlsh or cassandra-cli tools there.

Answer (score 2):

In Hive you cannot delete Cassandra data according to my knowledge. The [1] link given by Inosh describes how to archive Cassandra records older than a specific time duration. (e.g. records older than 3 months) All the archived data will be stored in a column family with the postfix, "_arch". In that feature a custom analyzer is used inside the generated Hive script to delete Cassandra rows. And also note that deleted records will take about 10 days to completely delete entire rows with it's row key. Until that happens you will see some empty fields associated with the Cassandra row ID.

Inosh's [2] is the real solution for your problem. Once incremental processing is enabled, hive script will process only the Cassandra rows unprocessed in the previous hive script execution. That means, the Hive will aggregate the values processed in each execution and will keep them for future. The next time hive will use that value, and previously processed last timestamp and process all the records came after that timestamp. The new aggregated value and older aggregated value will be used to get the overall value.

[1] - http://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM240/Archive+Cassandra+Data

[2] - http://docs.wso2.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=32345660

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cassandra data archival feature [1] to archive cassandra data.

Also refer to Incremental Analysis [2] which is a new feature released with BAM 2.4.0. Using that feature, received data can be analyzed incrementally, without processing all events in CFs.

[1] - http://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM240/Archive+Cassandra+Data

[2] - http://docs.wso2.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=32345660